# Dojo 1.6 dialog widget losing content attachpoints

Tags: javascript, dojo, dialog, nested

We've recently upgraded a project from Dojo 1.5 to 1.6 [for the basic IE9 support] and its broken one of our widgets. We have a dialog widget [dijit.Dialog] with another widget within it [any widget here will produce the same behavior], the expected behavior is for the inner widget to be placed within the dialog widget's contentNode, and each of their attachpoints to be available through the main widget.

This isn't happening, instead we only find the dialog's attachpoint. More details below:

We're doing something like this in our main widget's template:

```
<div dojoType="dijit.Dialog" dojoAttachPoint="dia_widget" 
    autofocus="true" draggable="false" open="false" preventCache="true">
    <div dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox" doLayout="false" dojoAttachPoint="val_widget">

    </div>
</div>
```

This provides us a parent widget [main_widget] with two attach points: dia_widget and val_widget, which could be accessed within the main widget [after the buildRendering() function] by calling `this.dia_widget` and `this.val_widget` respectively.

After upgrading to 1.6.0 things go awry.

My guess is that when a dialog widget gets parsed it removes the domNode of its content into its new containerNode. When the rootnode is having attachpoints assigned, since the domNode is no longer available, it wont get added.

I've been debugging and from what I can see `buildRendering()` calls `_attachTemplateNodes()` in dijit/_Templated.js. This loops over the nodes in the widget, looking for their `dojoattachpoint` attribute and pushing them in the widget's `_attachpoints` attribute.

The first loop has two nodes [our dia_widget and val_widget] nodes. At this point it then begins parsing each node individually, beginning by calling buildRendering() on dia_widget and finding the attachpoints of all its children.

At some point here the main_widget's dom is modified to include the parsed/rendered dia_widget. The loop then returns to the main node `_attachTemplateNodes()` call, where it only sees dia_widget as a child node, having lost the val_widget entry. Since the node isn't found, it never gets added as an attachpoint in main_widget, and we can't access it down the line.

I hope this isn't too convoluted to follow, I'm new to Dojo and chasing through the code in firebug wasn't the most fun experience in the world, so I've written things up as they make sense to me.

I'm left wondering why the behavior varies from 1.5 to 1.6, is this simply a feature/parameter I should be passing to the dialog to behave as it did before? Is this a bug in the way I'm creating the nested widget? Is this a [known?] bug in dojo itself?

Thanks,
vic

Comment: Investigated a little more with some help from wuhi in #dojo: this only occurs if the widget uses `dojox.dtl._Templated`, it works fine with `dijit._Templated`.

Comment: [Opened a bug on Trac](http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/12618)

Answer (score 0):

There are some changes in 1.6.0 that potentially adds a "lang" attribute to dynamically-loaded content.  Sometimes this "lang" attribute value is undefined and causes problems.

See if you are having problems with a "lang" attribute -- if so, this is likely to go away with 1.6.1.